# Upgrading a WinForms app to WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2008, upgrade

I have a side project that I wrote a few years ago in WinForms. To better help me learn WPF, I would like to rewrite it in WPF. Ideally, I would like to just modify the current project that I have and rewrite the UI in WPF instead of creating a new project.

I'm having some problems doing that. I did the following (using Visual Studio 2008 SP1):

1. Changed the Target Framework from 2.0 to 3.5.
2. Added PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, and WindowsBase references.

At this point, I noticed something was amiss. When I right clicked the project and selected Add | New Item, I did not have an option to create a WPF Window - the only WPF class that I could create is a WPF User Control. Since I had some other WPF projects around, I copied App.xaml.* and Window1.xaml.* from that project to mine, and updated them as necessary (basically just changing the namespace of that project to the namespace of my project).

I then deleted Program.cs (which previously contained the Main method, that displayed the main WinForm Form), and built the project. I got an error indicating that there is no Main method.

It seems like internally Visual Studio knows that this project is really a WinForms app, and not a WPF app. In a WPF project (created by selecting "WPF Application"), in the Application properties I can set the instance of the Application class as a start up object. In my WinForms converted project, that isn't an option.

I took a quick look at the .csproj file in a text editor, but I couldn't find anything that would tell Visual Studio that the project is really WinForms rather than WPF.

What else do I need to do to turn my WinForms project into a "real" WPF project? Do I have an option other than creating a new project and just replacing my current project?

**Update:** I took a closer look at the .csproj files, and I noticed that App.xaml was added as a page:

```
<Page Include="App.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Page>
```

However, in my other WPF project, it is an ApplicationDefinition. Once I changed that, I could set my Application instance as the start up object, and my app would run. I still don't have an option to create any WPF types other than User Controls, though.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I don't know for *certain* what in the project file informs Visual Studio what type of project is being used, but my guess is the "ProjectTypeGuids" is key.

My WPF projects have this:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>
   {60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};
   {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

[Here is a link](http://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx) I found which describes the guids and what kind of project they represent. You'll notice that the guid starting with "60DC" matches the list in the link for WPF applications.

Comment: My project didn't have a ProjectTypeGuids tag, but when I added them from another project (which had the same Guids as yours), that was enough to tell VisualStudio that this is a WPF project now. Thanks! :)

Comment: Here is another link describing in details how to convert a Winforms project to a WPF project. I just tested it and really seems great.  http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=1537&lang=en

Answer (score 26):

Sailing Judo's answer worked for me to convert a WinForms project into a WPF, but did not describe in detail what is needed;

1. Open the `csproj` file for the project you want to convert.
2. Search for the string `<ProjectTypeGuids>` - most likly it will not exist.
3. Add the following within the  tag of the project file. If you have multiple `PropertyGroup` tags, use the one without a `Condition` attribute (e.g. the default properties).

   > `<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>`
4. Save - if you have the project open VS will ask to reload the project.

From what I see and test, I can now easily add WPF Windows **and** WinForms. My older WinForms also work without problems.

Answer (score 2):

Open project manifest file (one with the .csproj extension) and modify PropertyGroup node (the one without Condition element) as below:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
     <ProjectTypeGuids>
         {60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
     </ProjectTypeGuids>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

After this modification restart VS. Now you can add WPF window or other WPF elements. You may also have to add references System.Xaml, PresentationCore and PresentationFramework.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly no.

WPF and Windows Forms projects aren't very compatible.

- Try to extract as much fussiness
  logic code into a class library
- Create a new blank solution
- Add a new WPF project to the solution
- Add the class library project to the
  solution
- Set the class library as a dependency of
  the WPF project
- Recreate the windows in WPF

Hope this works for you.

Best of luck with this endeavor!

Comment: While that would work, and I am sadly leaning towards going that route, somehow Visual Studio must know that this is a WinForms project, while the other project is a WPF project. How does it know this?

Comment: Properly something in proj file, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your csproj file:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

ProjectTypeGuids:

```
Windows (C#)           {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
Windows (VB.NET)       {F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}
Windows (Visual C++)   {8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}
Web Application        {349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}
Web Site               {E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}
WCF                    {3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}
WPF                    {60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548}
XNA (Windows)          {6D335F3A-9D43-41b4-9D22-F6F17C4BE596}
XNA (XBox)             {2DF5C3F4-5A5F-47a9-8E94-23B4456F55E2}
XNA (Zune)             {D399B71A-8929-442a-A9AC-8BEC78BB2433}
Silverlight            {A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B}
ASP.NET MVC            {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}
ASP.NET MVC 4          {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}
Test                   {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}
Solution Folder        {2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}
```