# Building wpf application as type of wpf class libarary

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

My need is to develop an addin for an application
but WPF application is not allowing to build it in type of **WPF Class Libarary**
Refering to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820850/create-a-wpf-library-in-visual-studio-express) i found that without XAML pages only we can build WPF application in Class Library Type. It it true? Or am I missing something?

I need to add a WPF window to my addin, but they are referring to remove all the windows and add usercontrol? Whats the workaround for it? Or am i doing anything wrong?

What i did now is I just deleted my application.xaml window from my solution and changed the target type to **WPF class Libarary** and builded the solution and it builded successfully. Is it correct way..? or any other ways there..? Am really new to this WPF !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go on creating a Class Library, adding a XAML view there. In your exe project you will include a reference to that lib and its public XAML windows or user controls should be available under the library's namespace, like any C# class.

Edit

A simple example from [GitHub](https://github.com/giuliohome/WPFLib): as you can see, the library project is compiled with a reference to the System.Xaml assembly.

**Edit 2**

To build an already existing Windows Application project into a Class Library one, besides changing the Output type you have to delete **only** the App.xaml

Comment: I couldnt get that ,i dont have any exe project

Comment: Have you added your xaml item to the library? What exactly is going wrong? Sha

Comment: Share the xaml you want to put in the library please

Comment: Am having more windows in that application.

Comment: Do you want me to show you a github example of a lib with one XAML as an example? How can I help you otherwise: I'm unclear where are you stuck...

Comment: Notice also my second edit: that should answer your initial question

Answer (score 0):

There two additional templates to build WPF dll's such as **WpfCustomControlLibrary** and **WpfControlLibrary**. You will then be able to add a Window (and other WPF-specific elements). And it can certainly contain general-purpose classes. And it will be built into an assembly no different from that from general class library project.

[How to: Create a WPF UserControl Library Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514641(v=vs.90).aspx)

[How to add a WPF control library template to Visual C# Express 2008](https://dotupdate.wordpress.com/2007/12/05/how-to-add-a-wpf-control-library-template-to-visual-c-express-2008/)

If you want just create class libary, please, just select **Class Library**

How to: [Create Class Library.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3cye135(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also, you can add Window to general class library project. **Visual Studio** just does not expose `Window` from add new items dialog. A workaround is to add a `User Control Item`, and then change it to derive from Window.