# How to convert a winforms project to wpf project

Tags: wpf, winforms

I converted a Winforms project by hand-editing the proj file. Changed project type guids and added an application definition section, and now I can add WPF Windows, Pages, etc. to the project. One thing that doesn't work is, the files I added do not have autogenerated cs files, and every new window component are missing their InitializeComponent method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a special reason you're doing it by hand?

Comment: Yes, instead of creating a new project and moving all the files and dll and COM references to the new one, I am trying to achieve an in-place conversion.

Comment: Don't bother to do what you're doing.  Make a new project file.

Comment: You read my previous comment? This is my preference because of the project size and other management requirements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a converter from WinForms to WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188186/is-there-a-converter-from-winforms-to-wpf)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading a WinForms app to WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450377/upgrading-a-winforms-app-to-wpf)

Answer (score 7):

If you unload the project you can edit the project file by adding/replacing the following element in the first `<PropertyGroup>` element:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

This will change the project type to a WPF project.

Comment: See also additional details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802745/1518546)