# Why doesn't Visual Studio want me to add a new window to my WPF project?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, window

Maybe a stupid question, but when I add item to a WPF project, Visual Studio only offers me UserControl, and not Window. Is this trying to encourage me to do MVVM, is my setup broken, or is there some other reason I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your project is probably configured as a WinForms project, or possibly as a class library.  If it's created as either of these, you are only able to add a WPF UserControl, unfortunately.

Of course, there's no technical reason for this limitation, so you can copy/paste one from another project or recreate/change your project to be a WPF project.

I'm not sure what you change exactly to make it a WPF project in VS's eyes.  You might try creating a new project and diffing it to your current project.  You will most likely have to do some text editing on your `.csproj` file.

Comment: Thanks, I copy-pasted this from another project, and now see the same as you: 
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>

Comment: Look at this answer. It details how to add WPF support to an existing project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450377/upgrading-a-winforms-app-to-wpf

Comment: Ultimately, take a look at this: http://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx

Answer (score 29):

Add this to your first `<PropertyGroup>` element in your csproj:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{24793F93-0FD8-4EC9-B1D2-028DB489B10D}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>nest_spawner</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>nest-spawner</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{24793F93-0FD8-4EC9-B1D2-028DB489B10D}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>nest_spawner</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>nest-spawner</AssemblyName>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Good tip! Works for me

Comment: Tried this but if I add that tag, VS fails to load the project, telling me "a project with the same name is already open in the solution". Any ideas?

Comment: Took a WinForms project and upgrade to WPF project using this. Worked for Visual Studio 2015 in Nov. 2016

Comment: VS2015 - perfect

Comment: It has automagically enabled window support for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try running **`devenv /installvstemplates`** to reset your installed templates.
I've used this before when the WPF User Control mysteriously disappeared from my add new list.

In my WPF project, when I click Add I get the following options (which includes Window).

[image: Add New Options]

So I'm afraid it's your setup.

Answer (score -3):

don't use Visual studio 2015 Microsoft Blend...
to open your project..
open your project in Visual Studio - Microsoft Visual Studio ,,,
see in title bar