# Correct Fractionate Application to some of Project in Once Solution

Tags: c#, wpf, solution

I am working on a WPF application. I need fractionate Application to some of Project in Once Solution and Add Refrences of Projects in Master Project same as BaseWindow.

This is worked without problem and run Projects from menu items . But there are Executable Sub Applications ( Projects ) in

"Solution\BaseWindow\bin\Debug" that are Runable alone! .

Please Help me what is correct fractionate Application in once Solution.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are these projects defined as class library?

Comment: @bbougot ! Thanks for reply . No . Each Project as a single complete Project with Forms and Controls and Opuputs . Indeed I dont know how to implement sub projects that run only by called from BaseWindow .

Comment: Well, if you really want one input, you should define all projects as class library except the one which hosts your BaseWindow. Then, add them as references inside your main project (which is your output application), and depending on your needs, you'll be able to use them. i.e: in your xaml, declare the namespace of each reference that you want to use, and same thing for your code-behind.

Comment: OK . My Solution have some of Class Library for tools, Common Processes and etc. 
But I dont know how to add "WPF Windows" to class that call direct from BaseWindow  when event occured . for example Mouse Click on a button.
Thanks again for your answers.

Comment: @bbougot ! thanks for your reply .
My problem has been solved by your guide .
I Found 2 Link that explain same as my problem in :
1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484403/why-doesnt-visual-studio-want-me-to-add-a-new-window-to-my-wpf-project
2) http://byteflux.me/converting-a-class-library-to-wpf-control-library/