# No creation of a WPF window in a DLL project?

Tags: wpf, dll, window

Is there a reason why Visual Studio won't let me create a WPF window in a DLL project?

I "solved" it by creating a window in an Application Project and copying it to my DLL project.
I also found that I could just create a UserControl and change the base class to "Window".

But if I had to do it this way, it's maybe because I shouldn't do it...

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Make sure the project type is `WPF User Control Library` when you create your project.

If it isn't then no sweat, just edit the csproj file and make sure the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` element under `Project/PropertyGroup` contain the following GUIDs

`<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>`

Also, make sure you reference PresentationFramework and System.Xaml in your project, or you will not get any WPF in your code.

Comment: Hello Florian, 
Thanks for your answer, I was indeed mistaking the project type and used "Class Library". :-s

Answer (score 15):

You can try adding new WPF User Control Item and change that to Window.

**Add New Item->WPF->User Control**

**In XAML:**

Change `<UserControl>` tag as `<Window>`

**In CS:**

Change base class from `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl` to `System.Windows.Window`.

Answer (score 8):

I do it this way:
1) create "WPF Application"
2) remove App.xaml
3) change Project properties -> Application  Output type: to Class Library (originally there is Windows Application)

Otherwise you will get errors:

"Library project file cannot specify ApplicationDefinition element"

"The project file contains a property value that is not valid"

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean that Visual Studio won't let you create a WPF window in a DLL project? Do you mean that if you right click the project, there is no option to add a Window there?

If that is the case, I think that means that you created a project type that isn't a WPF project type. I encountered something similar a while back when I wanted to upgrade a  WinForms project to use WPF instead - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450377/upgrading-a-winforms-app-to-wpf) for more information.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer, I was indeed mistaking the project type and used "Class Library". :-s