# New WPF Project Won't Compile -- Throws Error "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, wpf, compiler-errors, initializecomponent

I'm getting started with WPF, but when I create a new WPF project (usuing all default options) it won't compile after VS generates the project. (Both under C# and VB) I believe I'm running the latest/greatest VS (which is maybe the problem?)

Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012
Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3

Best I could tell none of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925584/the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) provided any help at all. The namespaces/class names are all correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled the .Net frameworks and reinstalled them and everything works again!  BTW, tried reinstalling VS and that had no effect, don't waste your time.

However, very shortly after this I ran into this problem:
[Error Reading Resource File for any WPF Project in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750270/error-reading-resource-file-for-any-wpf-project-in-vs2012)

However, it worked briefly before the problem started, so I'm not sure if this solution had anything to do with the new problem or not. Just be aware.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change a file name at any point?

Try Rebuild (not Build).

Comment: No. Used the default file name, default namespace, etc.

Comment: Note: It also failed when I tried with a non-default project name.

Comment: I am seriously wondering if this is a problem with VS Update 3?

Comment: I'm running VS 2012 with update 3 and I'm able to create a new project without any issue, so I don't think it's that.