# The name InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Nothing" Height="600" Width="800" MinHeight="450" MinWidth="400"/>
```

Mainwindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
    namespace View
    {
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
    }
```

It throws an error. **The namespaces are correct**, i tried rebuilding the solution, cleaning the solution, the xaml build action is set to Page. **The same code worked before**, then i changed the View namespace to View2 in both files, it started throwing errors, so i changed it back, but the same error appears. Is there anybody who solved this bug somehow (without creating a new solution and copying the files, which would obviously solve the problem)?

Comment: Which filed do you mean by "both files"?  Did you change the designer-generated file as well or just the two files you put in your question?

Comment: I changed it in MainWindow.xaml and in MainWindow.xaml.cs. Where else should i change it?

Comment: Are you saying that it throws an exception, or that you're getting a compiler error?

Comment: Build error: The name InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Esad Have you tried closing and reopening Visual Studio?

Comment: @CNuts Yes, many times. I'm stuck with this build error for 3 hours now. I guess I'll have to make a new solution and copy the code each time I change a namespace.

Comment: You may try to copy the contents of the MainWindow.xaml* files, remove them from the project, create a new window with the same name and paste in your code.

Comment: I created a new window, and it immediately gave the "InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context build" error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925584/the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: Thank you CNuts.  Closing and reopening did it for me.  I tried so many other things.  Wasted an hour on this.  Little issues like this keep cropping up.  since I switched to VS 2015