# How to add a new page to my project without getting the error "Initialize Component does not exist" when I build the application?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, build-error

I am trying to create a new page to my solution but I can't run the emulator because when I try to build the app I get the error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context.

I tried what is in this 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62671/initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-error
which basically says change the the "Build Action" to "Embeded Source". I tried it and the red squiggly line bellow the "Initialize Component" disappears but when i try to reference to that page for example when i want to open the page when a button is clicked I can't reference the page, the name doesn't come up with the intelliscence as it type the word "page1" an I get an error when i try to build the solution because it says " the type or namespace named page1 can not be found, are you missing using a directive or an assembly reference.

also another page suggests changing the page1.xaml build action to embeded source and making the page1.xaml.cs build action to compile. I can't do this because the page1.xaml doesn't get added to he solution explorer when I create a new page. so I can't select property and change the build action for page1.xaml.

also this page doesn't work because it is about wpf not xamarin.
[The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925584/the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context).

this link sais that the project runs fine although he has a red squigly line under the initialize component which isn't my case.
https://github.com/UXDivers/Grial-UI-Kit-Support/issues/154

this one sais clean and rebuild solves the build erro but it is not true in my case. 
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2863

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs if the xaml and xaml.cs page are not connected properly.

From the **Xaml Page**

```xml
<ContentPage 
      xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
      xmlns:controls="EmployeeApp.PettyCashListPage" 
      x:Class="EmployeeApp.PettyCashListPage">
```

The class in the line `x:Class="EmployeeApp.PettyCashListPage"` must match the name of the class in the file **Xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class PettyCashListPage : ContentPage
```

Both class names should match, if not 'InitializeComponent' issue occurs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Selvarathinam. It turns out the issue was that  I hadn't included the Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin package when I installed the application. After installing that package , it now works perfectly.  Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem  was that I hadn't included the Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin package when I installed the application. After installing that package , it now works perfectly.

A little side note: when I tried creating a new page before installing the package mentioned I used to get only the page.xaml.cs in the solution explorer. But after installing it , I now get both the page.xaml and the page.xamal.cs in the solution explorer and the problem is solved.