# Xamaria.form InitializeComponent does not exist in this context

Tags: xamarin.forms

Mainpage.xaml.cs

[image]

```
Mainpage.xaml
```

Anytime i run the application i got error code 
  The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925584/the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: I am new to xamaria i don;t understand that approach

Comment: did you search SO for 'InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context'? There appear to be literally hundres of Q/As on the error message.

Comment: please DO NOT post code as images.  You have told about this on previous questions.