# WPF InitializeComponent() error after adding reference to our project

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a new WPF on .net framework 4.6.1 and reference a project i've already created as a solution, but when i add the solution reference to the new project, the main window class has an error with InitializeComponent() - the name  "InitalizeComponent" does not exist in the current context.
code added below (default code after the new project was created):

```
namespace Gui
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the output window if there is an error processing the xaml file

Comment: Try to rebuild solution that works sometimes

Comment: What is the `BuildAction` property for `MainWindow.xaml` file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925584/the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)