# Error CS0103 when create a new .NET Maui project

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I use Visual Studio 2022 Community edition, when create a new .NET Maui project (from the type project selector) appears the error CS0103 on the ide, but the project compiles and executes fine, in android emulator or windows machine.
I check this post but don't works:
[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68046917/new-net-maui-app-project-throws-the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist)

[image]

the error: [CS0103  on InitializeComponent();](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0103))

Do you have some solution to this? thanks:

Entire error:

Error   CS0103  El nombre 'InitializeComponent' no existe en el contexto actual MauiApp1 (net8.0-android), MauiApp1 (net8.0-ios), MauiApp1 (net8.0-maccatalyst), MauiApp1 (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0)  C:\Users\Jordi\source\repos\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MainPage.xaml.cs  9   Activo

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Code and errors should be posted as text, not images.  And please include the entire error message, not just the error code.  I've been using C# for 20 years and I don't have any of the error code memorized.

Comment: :-) you can see the error code on the title of the post

Comment: please read what I actually said: "please include the **entire error message**, not just the error code"

Comment: ok sorry! I have modified ( but is in Spanish)

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself!
I found the solution! ( execute Visual Studio as Administrator )
sorry, moderators can delete this post if they feel it is not relevant!
Thanks!!