# The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context in my WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

I have recently converted my .NET Framework 4.8 WPF application to .NET5. When I compile the application, I am get below error

> The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925584/the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) but couldn't helped me much.

I checked both `*.xaml` and `*.cs` file namespace.

```
<Window x:Class="Cl.Wpf.MessageWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight"
        Title="MessageWindow" >
```

Also checked `.cs` file

```
namespace Cl.Wpf
{
    public partial class MessageWindow : Window
    {                     

        public MessageWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
             .....
        }
```

My `*.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Cl.Wpf</RootNamespace>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers" Version="0.2.241603">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I also tried deleting `obj` folder and restarted visual studio 2019 but also did not help me out.

Also, tried adding some space in the `XAML` file but that didn't help as well.

[image: xaml]

Build Action `MessageWindow.xml`

[image: Build Action for MessageWindow.xml]

Comment: Could be you need to edit the project file and add `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`.
Also `net5.0-windows` as TF.
For details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/5.0/sdk-and-target-framework-change

Comment: Hi @lidqy, `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` is already there in the project file.

Comment: Hhm. I don't know. Project file looks okay to me.
Do the file names match: `MessageWindow.xaml.` and `MessageWindow.xaml.cs`

Is the CSharp-file displayed as a "child" of the XAML file in the Solution explorer?

Comment: Also : do  all dependencies resolve? Do you have yellow icons over one of the entries?

Comment: And one more : What's your VS 2019 version? It seems there were issues in older releases that caused that bug with InitializeComponent ... https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/wpf-project-on-net-core-3-the-name-initializecompo/745596

Comment: Hi @lidqy, I have attached screenshot in the question. yes there is no error in the dependencies section. My visual studio version is `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.0`.

Comment: OK, last one: What's the "Build Action" for "MessageWindows.xaml" in the property tab for that file? Should be "Page"

Comment: Ensure that the Build Ation of the MainWindow.xaml file is set to Page.

Comment: Add a new window to the project. Move/copy the contents over from the existing file and then delete the existing file.

Comment: Hi @lidqy, The `Build Action` for `MessageWindows.xml` is `Page`. I  tried creating new window to the same project but nothing helped.

Comment: @BionicCode, `Build Action` for `MessageWindows.xml` is Page only. I also have attached screenshot.

Comment: @mm8 I tried creating new window to the same project but nothing helped.  I also even tried creating a new wpf solution but still I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the issue is with `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.2`.

I reinstalled the community version but did not work again.

So finally, I uninstalled community version and reinstalled `Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.2` and fortunately it worked for me.

I am not sure how useful this would be for other users but this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this solution here because I encountered this issue under very similar circumstances in that I moved my WPF solution from .NET Framework to .NET 7. I also am using VS Community Edition. Version is 2022 17.4.1

In my case I could nuke the obj folder and clean my project, close, and reopen VS and there would be no errors. I could code and intellisense would happily throw me suggestions. However, as soon as I ran my project, the intellisense errors would show up on every single namespace variable assocated with a XAML view.

My XAML pages build actions were set to page and my C# code behind pages build actions were set to C# compiler.

I switched my C# code behind build actions to "Page" and then switched them back to C# Compiler and the issue mysteriously vanished.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen to me, what fixed it was:

1. Close VS2022
2. Delete the contents of the OBJ folder
3. Open VS