# How do you make a WPF application from an Empty Project?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

When coding WinForms applications, I always start with an empty project, then add an Application Class, Forms, etc...  In doing so, I can build up the application from scratch, keeping it clean, without all the "fluff" of the Standard WinForms projects, which add Forms, etc... for you.

I want to do the same with WPF.  I've created my application class, made a Window class and I can run the application just fine, but there is no XAML associated with the window because I'm just declaring it as a derived class from Window.

My question is, can WPF -Windows be added to a project like WinForms -Forms such that the XAML is also added and the designer can be used to layout the controls etc...?  Or do I have to use the canned "WPF Project" and go from there?

***Apparently it's not possible to create an Empty Project and add XAML backed Windows.  If anyone knows why, I would appreciate an explanation. (You can, however, create programmatically generated windows, or if you want your own startup object in a default WPF Project, simple delete the App.xaml and add your own class with a static Main().)***

```
class OrderEntry : System.Windows.Application
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] commandLine)
        {
            OrderEntry app = new OrderEntry();
            app.MainWindow = new WindowMain();
            app.MainWindow.Show();
            app.Run();
        }
    }

public partial class WindowMain : System.Windows.Window
{

}
```

Works fine, but WindowMain has no XAML associated with it.

Comment: Add WpfWindow instead of Simple class

Comment: If you need to create a WPF application. Use `File -> New Project -> WPF Application.` The default WPF project is clean. Don't try to reinvent the wheel. It's already been invented by Microsoft and they know much better than any of us.

Comment: @HighCore - IMO the default WPF project is not clean.  It contains a lot of "magic"; but you're certainly correct, and as stated in the question, one can use the default canned project.

Comment: @user2942249 I have no idea what you mean by "magic". There is only 1 `ApplicationDefinition`, and a default `Window`, which can be removed. There is no "magic" at all.

Comment: @HighCore - Where is the code with Application.Run?

Comment: @user2942249 there is no such thing. `Application.Run()` is defined in `PresentationFramework.dll`.

Comment: @HighCore - Thus it's magic.  In my sample above I'm creating a custom window and running the application loop on that window.  None of that is present in a canned WPF project.

Comment: @ethicallogics - You'll have to provide a sample of that, but it appears that's really a VisualStudio bound class.

Comment: @user2942249 Wrong. The `Main()` method is generated in `App.g.i.cs` which is autogenerated by the `Build Action` of the `App.xaml` file. Why do you care about any of that? If you don't want that, remove the `App.xaml` file altogether, and define the `Main()` method yourself.

Comment: @HighCore - Now you're starting to answer my question thanks for editing your comment.

Comment: @HighCore - So I have to delete the App.xaml and then I can define my own application entry point?

Comment: @user2942249 Yes. I still fail to see the need for this. You're losing your time.

Comment: @HighCore - While your attitude and disposition leave a lot to be desire, I wanted thank you for the tip of deleting the App.xaml, it has set me on the right course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgrading a WinForms app to WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450377/upgrading-a-winforms-app-to-wpf)

Comment: Alright, knock it off, both of you. I deleted the comments that I thought weren't constructive from both of you. Let's keep this focused on the technical issues at hand.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, yes - XAML based windows can be added to the project as and when you want.

The trick is to ensure your project *type* is correct, because this governs the list of template items that you will see when you go `Add->New...`

If you find the right project in your Solution Explorer, right click and select `Unload Project`, then right click it again and select to `Edit`, you will then get the proj file in XML format. In it you will see a line similar to the following:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Those GUIDs dictate what project or file templates you will see in the add list. You can find more details in the previous SO question [*Visual Studio project type guids*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10802198/109702) and the blog post linked in one of the answers [*INFO: List of known project type Guids*](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx)

Comment: There's one more tiny modification which is hard to notice. WPF apps have `[assembly:ThemeInfo]` attribute in `AssemblyInfo.cs`. The rest is just copy-pasting correct project items.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have tried, it worked for me

1. Create an empty project from Visual Studio 2013 Templates
   [image]
2. Add reference for below dll's which are present at Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\
   [image]
3. Modify the .csproj file located at project root folder through a text editor. Add below entry for `<ProjectTypeGuids>` in `<PropertyGroup>` node.

   {60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

[Read more about Project Type Guids here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802198/visual-studio-project-type-guids)

4. Change the `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
   <ProjectGuid>{C60226AB-DDB6-49C2-8B0D-F59E6B590236}</ProjectGuid>
   <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
   <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
   ```
5. Add a App.Xaml file to your application and replace its content like this

Note here *WpfApplication1* is the default namespace and we haven't created *MainWindow.xaml* yet

6. Modify the code behind and inherit it from Application
   [image]
7. Modify the .csproj to add `<ApplicationDefinition>` under `<ItemGroup>`

eg:

```
  <ItemGroup>
     <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Note MainWindow is a file which I have added later.

Now we can create XAML backed windows

Comment: @pirate-x it seems the edit has removed the App.Xaml contents :)

Comment: It actually did. Please code format it, must have been my bad. Apologies.

Comment: Changing the App.xaml from a Page to an ApplicationDefinition in the project file solved the error I was getting about the missing static 'Main' method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As HighCore said in comments that using given WPF FCL/Template are best I also agree with that . But if you still wants your own xaml Then do this

> > 1) Add Xml file to your View Project and keep its extension .xaml say WindowMain.xaml
> >
> > 2) Remove the below line from it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

> > 3)Copy and Paste

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

</Window>
```

> > 4) add x:class attribute to Window element like and set another attribute like Title height width etc

```
 <Window x:Class="Namespace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MyWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

</Window>
```

> > 5) Close the project and edit project file like

```
<Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Page>

<Compile Include="MyWindow.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MyWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
```

//or MainWindow.cs 
      MainWindow.xaml
      Code

> > 6) Save and close
> >
> > 7)Open your project you will find your .cs file under .xaml file as we mentioned it in DependentUpon
> >
> > 8) Add Constructor to your partial class and call InitializeComponent() method

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

This worked for me . But this is all we doing what Wpf exactly provide by itself by using their WPF Window . And I have assumed that your App class builded and worked correctly but I doubt it you calling window Show before App Run. I hope this will help.

Comment: @user2942249 use the default WPF project template.

Comment: @HighCore - The point of the question is 'how do you start a project from scratch without the template'?  The answer of 'use the default template' isn't an acceptable answer.  Acceptable answers are of the form 'yes this is possible and here's how' or 'no this is not possible because of x, y and z'

Comment: @user2942249 my problem is that you have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You're not giving any reasons `why` you want to do that to begin with. It's as if you asked... "how can I make 2 == 1 in C#? - What do you want that for? It makes no sense

Comment: @HighCore - I gave a reason in the question, because that's how I make my WinForms projects, from an Empty Project.

Comment: @HighCore - Why can't add a "WPF Window" be added from an empty project?  There's got to be reasonable explanation.

Comment: @user2942249 because the `Project Item Template` is registered in Visual Studio for a specific `Project Type`.

Comment: @HighCore - Then why can a WinForm be added to an Empty Project and not a WPFWindow?